# How do I login on WebSphere Portal with ADFS using SAML with custom login page (I don't want to login with ADFS default login page)?

Tags: websphere, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, adfs, watson

We have requirement to implement SSO using Microsoft ADFS on WebSphere Portal, IBM Watson, IBM Connection and IBM Cognos, to achieve it we have configured ADFS with WebSphere portal. Now we can login on portal using ADFS default login page.

As per requirement user can login on portal with his/her email, mobile etc. which we can't achieve with ADFS default login page therefore we have to created custom login app.

Please suggest how to login on portal with custom app with ADFS

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to customize ADFS server's sign-in page. See this link:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn280950%28v=ws.11%29.aspx